# #1067 - Invalid default value for DATETIME 'add_time'

Tags: mysql, algorithm

When I import csgonitro_csgonitro.gz, this error shows up

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9lZy.png

Mysql says there is an 'invalid default value' for a DATETIME column. The default value specified is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

These are the contents of csgonitro_csgonitro.gz
http://pastebin.com/pGbGtvah

I have 0 to no knowledge of PHP, mySQl, so a walkthrough to do what i need to do to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what version of mysql are you using? Some older versions don't convert between DATETIME and TIMESTAMP automatically. You could declare your add_time column to be a TIMESTAMP instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using phpmyadmin to create your tables. Possibly importing from a different version of mysql.

Depending on what you can or want to do you have several options:

- update your mysql version (may not be possible because you're not in charge of the server)
- change the add_time column to remove the default current_timestamp
  `` `add_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL, ``
- change the add_time column to change the datatype to timestamp
  `` `add_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ``

The first option won't require any change in your PHP code. The other 2 options probably will.

Changing to a null default value means you'll have to make sure your application will fill in a value when items are added.

Changing to a TIMESTAMP will require your application to convert between timestamps and dates when reading from the database.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL (before version 5.6.5) does not allow functions to be used for default DateTime values.

Try updating MySQL and it should work.